# Magento 1.9: Collecting information from form

Tags: magento-1.9

I'm completely new to Magento and I was looking into ways I could implement a form that collects customer name and email information by writing the information into CSV file.

I know a custom module might be a way to solve this issues but I don't know how to implement it, or if you guys can think of a better way to solve this that would be much appreciated!

Comment: When do you want to collect that information?

Comment: I want to collect that information after the user clicks the submit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a custom module, as you have already noted.
I can't give you the complete code, but here's an outline; if you try this and have a more specific question, just open a new one here.

**app/etc/modules/Myname_Mymodule.xml**
This file tells Magento that your module is there.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Myname_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Myname_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Myname/Mymodule/etc/config.xml**
Your module configuration that tells Magento what your module does.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Myname_Mymodule>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Myname_Mymodule>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <myname_mymodule>
                <class>Myname_Mymodule_Model</class>
            </myname_mymodule>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <myname_mymodule>
                <class>Myname_Mymodule_Helper</class>
            </myname_mymodule>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <myname_mymodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Myname_Mymodule</module>
                    <frontName>myname_mymodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </myname_mymodule>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <myname_mymodule>
                    <file>myname_mymodule.xml</file>
                </myname_mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

What the config.xml actually does, is: it registers the shortnames of your helpers, models and blocks that you can use in `Mage::getModel(...)`, `Mage::helper(...)` and `Mage::getLayout()->createBlock(...)`. It also registers a new URL (route). We will send your form there.

**app/design/frontend/base/default/templates/myname_mymodule/form.phtml**
Put your form here :) Send it to the URL `$this->getUrl('myname_mymodule/index/save')`

**app/code/local/Myname/Mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php**

```
<?php

class Myname_Mymodule_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function saveAction() {
        $postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();

        // TODO validate post data
        // TODO save post data to CSV file


        // afterwards, show a nice message & redirect the user to the previous page
        $session = Mage::getSingleton('core/session');
        if($success) {
            $session->addSuccess(Mage::helper('myname_mymodule')->__("IT WORKED"));
        } else {
            $session->addError(Mage::helper('myname_mymodule')->__("Something went wrong."));
        }

        $this->_redirectReferer();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank so much for all your help! I have created a new .phtml file for the form (/app/design/frontend/default/default/template/myname.phtml) and created a page where the block refers to this piece of code. For the submit button, I currently have it written as: <input type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Submit') ?>" /> but should I make the submit button use the code to validate the post data and save post data to CSV file? I'm confused how this should all link together.

Comment: As @simonthesorcerer mentioned you have to put form action like this <form action="$this->getUrl('myname_mymodule/index/save')"> so after submit button click form action called saveAction of app/code/local/Myname/Mymodule/controllers/IndexController.php file where you can get information of form using this "$this->getRequest()->getPost()".

Also for form validation you can refer this article https://inchoo.net/magento/out-of-the-box-form-validation-in-magento/ . Thanks.